# How to get python-dev for windows?

Tags: python, django

We are trying to install PIL and getting the error

`error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Many similar questions, including this one ([installing Reportlab (error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325305/installing-reportlab-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1)), suggest installing the `python-dev` package.

Where can this be sourced for Windows 7. `pip install python-dev` didn't work.

Comment: the answer is right on the PIL website, they have downloads for windows

Answer (score 20):

It seems there is no `python-dev` package for Windows. But the Python installer for Windows will normally install a sub directory `include` inside the main Python dir.

So with Python in `C:\Python` you would get:

- C:\Python
- C:\Python\DLLs
- C:\Python\Doc
- **C:\Python\include**
- C:\Python\Lib
- C:\Python\libs
- C:\Python\Scripts
- C:\Python\tcl
- C:\Python\Tools

Inside this `include` directory you will find `Python.h`, which can be included or referenced.

Comment: I am able to include Python.h, but I have no pyconfig.h. So I am getting `Python-2.7.13\Include/Python.h:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: @MeetTaraviya I’m afraid you’ll have to make that a separate question, because I haven’t done much Python development since answering … don’t remember having needed `pyconfig.h`. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678231/1548776 is a good hint?

Comment: @MeetTaraviya Also have a look at https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/PC/pyconfig.h. https://github.com/esa/pagmo/wiki/Guide-to-Compilation-on-Windows-x64#patch-python-pyconfigh suggests `pyconfig.h` *is* included …

Comment: @MeetTaraviya Good to hear you were able to solve it. Would you please explain briefly for the benefit of others with the same problem?

Comment: I founnd out python-config on the system, ran `python-config --ldflags` and added those flags to linking option

Answer (score 3):

When I used to develop on Windows, this website with pre-compiled binaries was extremely handy: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

You'll find pre-compiled versions of PIL and ReportLab there. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: There is no 64-bit version for Python 2.7

Comment: @user1328021 Sorry, see the PIL website for the 64-bit version. You didn't mention anything in your question about 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get a complete working setup on Windows, including ming compiler, is to install a distribution such as [pythonxy](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) (my favorite) or [EDP](https://www.enthought.com/).