# Installing python development libraries on windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I want to install sasl.h header in my C:/python27/include folder which I browsed the internet and found could be done by

```
python-dev libsasl2-dev
```

if on Linux environment. What to do if I am on windows ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get python-dev for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448710/how-to-get-python-dev-for-windows)