# Fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++

Due to the nature of a program I am making, I decided to attempt to embed python into it. So I downloaded the python source code, and linked the `includes` and `libs`. I put `#include <Python.h>` at the top of the code and when I tried to compile it, it took me straight to `Python.h` and said "Fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory". I know the compiler isn't wrong, because I checked the include folder and I couldn't find the file, so I don't know why the file isn't there. BTW: I got the Python files by downloading the source code on the python website

Comment: Linux ? Windows ? Python version ?

Comment: @Caduchon Whoops, I am using Windows and Python 3.4.2

Comment: With python 2.7.6 I find the file under Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Caduchon I just downloaded Python 3.7.9 and I can't find pyconfig.h

Comment: @Caduchon Not in Python 2.7.6 either. I feel I might be looking in the wrong place, or getting the wrong thing

Comment: I found the file in `path_to_install_dir/include/python2.7` under Linux and `path_to_install\include` under Windows. Did you download the official version on python.org ?

Comment: @Caduchon It is definitely from python.org, but it is downloaded under source code rather than an installation file, so I'm not sure if I have to compile it or something

Comment: You are right. See my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure or compile Python. When I open the file `pyconfig.h` in my Python installation, it begins with :

```
/* pyconfig.h.  Generated from pyconfig.h.in by configure.  */
/* pyconfig.h.in.  Generated from configure.ac by autoheader.  */
```

Comment: What do we use to generate pyconfig.h.in into pyconfig.h? @Caduchon

Comment: @LukeDev what is your configuration ? Windows ? Linux ? Other ? Under Linux (openSUSE) it's generated by the configure tool in the Python directory.

Comment: I'm on linux, I figured that out by reading some documentation on the python website