# Python-Dev For WIndows and Cgo

Tags: python, c, mingw-w64, cgo

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448710/how-to-get-python-dev-for-windows) post about using python-dev for windows. I am using cgo and when i `#include "C:/Python/include/Python.h"` it says:

```
C:/Python/include/cpython/pystate.h:9:10: fatal error: cpython/initconfig.h: 
No such file or directory
 #include "cpython/initconfig.h"
```

I saw that the post i referenced was using windows 7, and I am using windows 10, so maybe that is the issue? How do i do this?

Also, I dont know if this is relevant, but i am using cgo for this.

Also I am running this gcc

```
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```