# Windows fatal error 'python.h' file not found 'gcc'

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, cython

I can't figure out what I made wrong I look on almost every forum but I only found answer for linux. I'm trying to compile a python project. It my first time I compile a project I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

I start with cython so I have a .c file of my project and I download gcc add it path into json and I run it. And TADA I have a beautiful error message.

Comment: Post your build command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get python-dev for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448710/how-to-get-python-dev-for-windows)

Comment: sorry what is my build command?

Comment: @Traclat to find the full build command you need to look at the logs/terminals where the actual compilation is happening. This depends on your IDE (In VSCode it is a tab called  "Output")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.