# pip install reportlab error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, reportlab

use ubuntu virtualenv. I try to install reportlab

the command is

```
pip install reportlab
```

in this directory

```
(company2)stefano@stefano-X550EP:~/htdocs/company2$
```

the error is

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

actually the pip list is:

```
argparse (1.2.1)
Django (1.7.7)
html5lib (0.999)
pip (1.5.4)
pisa (3.0.33)
PyPDF2 (1.24)
setuptools (2.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
xhtml2pdf (0.0.6)
```

I need reportlab to use xhtml2pdf because now the django project gives me this error:

```
No module named reportlab.lib.colors
```

Comment: Could you post the full error log of `pip install`?

Answer (score 12):

without your full error log, it is impossible to tell.  But I bet you are just missing python-dev.

try installing it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

then pip install reportlab again.

hope that helps.

see: [installing Reportlab (error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325305/installing-reportlab-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 3):

The sudo apt-get install python-dev is almost correct. But if you are using Python 3.x you need to change it to install python3-dev. This made all the difference in my django, postgresql, venv setup.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same issue while installing readability-lxml a python package. Then I tried installing following packages, and it worked for me.

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It majorly depends on the type of packages you suppose to install. Frequently its failing due to the missing of [libsasl2-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libsasl2-dev) a package for authentication abstraction library which uses in the Ubuntu version

First, install:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

then run:

```
sudo pip install sasl
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late. But after searching all over this is what solved mine. It need c++ compiler for reportlab. Try Installing g++, the c++ compiler

```
sudo apt install g++
```