# Failed building wheel for

Tags: python

I'm trying to install Pillow using

```
pip install pillow
```

But everytime it does that:

---

Failed building wheel for Pillow                 Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow

Command "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-rzy91xcz/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-d_if45hl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-rzy91xcz/pillow/

It also says that:

unable to execute 'aarch64-linux-android-clang': No such file or directory                        error: command 'aarch64-linux-android-clang' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Have you tried installing [```clang```](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/k/how-to-install-latest-clang-5.0-on-ubuntu-16.04-xenial-wsl.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install reportlab error: command 'x86\_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778715/pip-install-reportlab-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit-sta)

Comment: None of that works

Comment: If you're trying to cross-compile for Python on Android, you need a clang cross-compiler for Android, not just your native clang.

Comment: I succeed installing pillow in the last bit I deleted data because my terminal ran into a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing clang

```
pkg install clang
```

Thank you to abarnet and sorry for late answer to myself haha I'm late because I sixed this week ago.

Comment: Any other option, I installed clang and still isn't working!